# Why it is must to import "react" even if my client.js is not using it

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and got little confused when my code didn't work when I didn't imported "React" in my client.js. Ideally when I am not using "React" in my code therefore I should not forced to import "react" module. Following is code snippet.

Layout.js:

```
import React from "react";

export  default class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.name = "Dilip";
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <h1>Welcome {this.name} in React world !!</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import  Layout from "./components/Layout"

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, app);
```

Not working Code:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import  Layout from "./components/Layout"

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, app);
```

Why it doesn't work when I removed code to import "React"? I am not using "React" anywhere therefore it should work. It throws following error in console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

Note: I am following [video](http://htps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vu_rIMPROoQ)

Comment: ReactDOM depends on React

Comment: That I understand, but its not visible to new user like me when I am using "ReactDOM". If it depends on "react" then it should take as parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Matteo is wrong. Though `ReactDOM` does depend on `React`, it is requiring it itself in its code.

The reason why you need to import `React`, is the `JSX` snippet :

```
<Layout/>
```

Which is only syntactic sugar for :

```
React.createElement(Layout)
```

Therefore, after JSX compilation, React is effectively needed. ;)

Comment: This make sense. Since JSX use the shortcut syntax therefore "React" is hidden from syntax but technically its being used. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: Thanks for in deep clarification

Answer (score 1):

ReactDOM depends on React. [From NPM Package Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom), you can see you need to use in couple:

> npm install **react** react-dom

And the description talk about:

> It is intended to be paired with the isomorphic React, which will be
>   shipped as react to npm.

Hope this clarify